# making 2 different sample arrays (without repeated array elements)

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make 2 different sample arrays, I know how to make a sample like this:

```
x_1 = randsample(1:10,5,true);
x_2 = randsample(1:10,5,true);
```

But I would like `x_2` to be a different sample, I mean that not any element of the array be repeated in the other `x_1` array. Is there any easy function in Matlab to do this without having to test each element and change it manually?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to just sample twice as many times from the distribution and then split the result into two pieces. Then you are guaranteed to have no repeated values within or between the arrays.

```
% Sample 10 times instead of 5 (5 for each output)
samples = randsample(1:10, 10);

%     2    10     4     5     3     8     7     1     6     9

% Put half of these samples in x1
x1 = samples(1:5);

%     2    10     4     5     3


% And the other half in x2
x2 = samples(6:end);

%     8     7     1     6     9
```

An alternative approach if you want to allow duplicates *within* an array. Then you'd just modify the input sample to the second `randsample` call by removing anything that appeared in the first.

```
% Define the initial pool of samples to draw from
samples = 1:10;

x1 = randsample(samples, 5, true);

%     5     4     8     8     2

% Remove things in x1 from samples
samples = samples(~ismember(samples, x1));

x2 = randsample(samples, 5, true);

%     6     6     7     9     9
```